# Zbrush to Blender model, wrong/sharp shading issue with Cycles

Tags: topology, shadows, smooth, zbrush

I have a shading problem when using a model from zbrush to blender. My faces become non-planar and this is ruining all the shading. (Giving artifacts, sharp shadows)

How can I solve this shading issue/ make all faces flat?

To fix this faces I tried:

1. Smooth shading
2. Edge split modifier/ weighten normals
3. Mesh -> Clean Up -> Make Planar Faces (fix one plane but break all nearby)
4. Clear Custom split normal
5. (Geometry Data) Export from Zbrush as smooth/flat normals
6. Import to Blender with NO custom normals
7. Blender 3.6 and 4.0
8. Different models (mine and Zbrush standard)
9. FBX and obj formats
   [image: Cycles render viewport, wireframe]

Comment: Maybe your object is REALLY small ? That often occurs whan importing/exporting and can cause that kind of issue.

Comment: My object really is small in blender... Its 0.1/0.02/0.1 m according to dimensions. But when I scale it (x100) to 10m/2m/10m (XYZ), it still have this things (less of them, but still)... Or I have to import already scaled object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

How and what I did:

1. Scale up my model to the possible real size. (It was VERY small.) This reduced the number of artifacts.
2. Go to the "Object" tab (orange box) -> "Shading" -> "Shadow Terminator" and increase the "Shading Offset" until the problem is solved (0.3 was fine for me).
3. *Instead of tweaking the "Shadow Terminator" values, consider adding 1-2 levels of subdivision (or more) to your model. **Additional geometry solves the problem best if you can afford it.**